# How to implement competing risk analysis in IPTW (inverse probability of treatment weighting) cohort by R

Tags: r

Because the baseline characters of two group were different, IPTW were used to balance the two groups, and it has been done in R. "cmprsk" package in R were used to get cumulative incidence curves (CIFs) for competing risk. I know how to get a non-weigted CIF in the crude cohort, however, I don't know how to creat a weighted CIF in IPTW cohort. In previous reports, we have noticed this function can be implemented by SAS or Stata, but we don't have the access to the two software, so how to implement Inverse probability of treatment-weighted competing risks analysis in R is very important for me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The cmprskcoxmsm package of R does implement IPTW competing risks analyses
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cmprskcoxmsm/cmprskcoxmsm.pdf